# proxey scheme error in the normal terminal but not in vs code terminal

Tags: python, proxy, py-telegram-bot-api

i have this telegram bot that i made and im getting no error in vs code, but when i run the exact same command in the bash terminal it throws an error.
[image]

here's the code that sets up the proxy:

```
httpcoreProxy = SyncHTTPProxy((b'http', b'127.0.0.1', 39459, b''))
proxy = {'http':'http://127.0.0.1:39459', 'https':'http://127.0.0.1:39459'}
apihelper.proxy = proxy

translatorProxy = {'http': httpcoreProxy, 'https':httpcoreProxy}
translator = googletrans.Translator(proxies=translatorProxy)
```

and the 127.0.0.1:39459 is just my local lantern proxy.